# How to switch table prefix in a module in Drupal 6?

Tags: 6, database

I have multiple sites setup on a single MySQL database in Drupal 6. The sites each have their own prefix, such as site1_, site2_, etc. I'm wondering how I can switch the current table prefix inside of a module to check the variables on each site. For example, I want to check the preprocess_css variable on every site by looping through each sites settings file and running variable_get('preprocess_css') and get the variable for each site. I can get the table prefix and get the variable using db_query on the variables table, but I know there has to be a way to set the current table prefix inside a module so I can just run variable_get inside a loop with each table prefix. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with [variable_get()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/6) is that it doesn't read values from the database, but from a global variable, which is initialized during the Drupal bootstrap.

```
function variable_get($name, $default) {
  global $conf;

  return isset($conf[$name]) ? $conf[$name] : $default;
}
```

What you should do is use code similar to the following one.

```
$variables = array();
$old_db_prefix = $GLOBALS['db_prefix'];
$GLOBALS['db_prefix'] = 'site1_';
$result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {variable}');

while ($variable = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $variables[$variable->name] = unserialize($variable->value);
}

$GLOBALS['db_prefix'] = $old_db_prefix;
```

Then you can read the value of, e.g., *preprocess_css*, with `$variables['preprocess_css']`.

You could use code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_variable_get($db_prefix, $name, $default) {
  $old_db_prefix = $GLOBALS['db_prefix'];
  $GLOBALS['db_prefix'] = $db_prefix;
  $value = db_result(db_query("SELECT value FROM {variable} WHERE name = '%s'", array($name)));
  $GLOBALS['db_prefix'] = $old_db_prefix;

  return !empty($value) ? unserialize($value) : $default;
}
```

Bear in mind that some Drupal variables can be overridden with a value set in the settings.php file, which can contains code similar to the following one.

```
$conf = array(
  'preprocess_css' => FALSE,
);
```

What you read from the database could not be the value set for that Drupal site, for the Drupal variable you are reading.

Answer (score 0):

The prefix is stored as one of the variables in the settings.php file, all of which are made `global` early on in the page build process.

That in mind, you can do something as easy as:

```
$GLOBALS['db_prefix'] = 'db1_';
print variable_get('site_name', 'default'); // Site name from first set of tables

$GLOBALS['db_prefix'] = 'db2_';
print variable_get('site_name', 'default'); // Site name from second set of tables
```

Bear in mind that this change won't persist across page loads so you'll need to do your processing in a single load, or implement some sort of system to track which prefix you should currently be using.